# List not returning the proper values as an output

Tags: python, list, function, return

I am trying to write a small function (as an exercise). This function takes a list of values and returns the values that are odd numbers. I have gotten the function to give me the right answer with the print() function, but I am not able to do the same with a return statement.

```
def odd_nr(list1):
    i = 0
    for list1[i] in list1:
        if list1[i] % 2 != 0:
            print(list1[i])
            i += 1
    return list1

odd_nr([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

The output is:

```
1
3
5
[1, 3, 5, 6, 5, 6]
```

I am not able to figure out why the return statement gives this output. I tried different indentations, I tried different variants of the return statement, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are just returning the original list without modification.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nah, they're modifying it, and you can see it in the output.

Comment: @HeapOverflow oh jeez, yeah, the `for list1[i] in list1`.

Comment: This reads like a bizarre hybrid of a `while` loop and a `for` loop that that avoids a syntax error more by accident than by intent.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
def odd_nr(list1):
    results = []
    for number in list1:
        if number % 2 != 0:
            print(number)
            results.append(number)
    return results

odd_nr([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

**Further Explanation**:

Any function can take something and return something. This something can also be nothing, `None`.

Your function takes a list, and returns a list, but it is returning the same list that it is taking in.

The `print` statement is *not* a return value. Which means a `print` is not something that the function returns, it is a side-effect, a side door, for us humans to see, mostly.

To return a list of only odd numbers, you need to collect them in *another* list as you iterate through your original input list.

Then once you are done, `return` the list that has collected all the odd numbers. Hope this helps.

I also updated your code a bit, `for list1[i] in list1`, even though it works, it is hard to understand and it does so for the wrong reasons, see below. You can simply do `for number in list1` and also not worry about incrementing any counters(`i` in your case).

**Explanation on why `for list1[i] in list` works**:

This is interesting. By choosing `list1[i]` as the current iteratee, we will be mutating our list while iterating; it is lucky that each iteratee is equal, in value to the list element it is mutating. Here is an example to illustrate what is happening. It is easy to see when we do not update `i`:

```
list1= [1,2,3,4]
i=0
for list1[i] in list1:
    print(list1[i])
print(list1)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
[4, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @HeapOverflow, yes it does, but see my explanation I added.

Comment: Yeah, but I wouldn't call it "lucky". And if you don't remove the `i += 1`, it's a correct algorithm except for returning too much (see my answer).

Comment: I do believe it is a coincidence at least with respect to the OP's intentions, and my own confusion as to why it works. If the standard is to _just work_ binary code will do just fine. Programming languages are written for and read by humans, so it is very important for them to be immediately obvious. I would go on to say even though that approach works, it is a bad approach for any real world use cases.

Comment: Hmm, to me it was immediately obvious :-). Then again, I wrote that algorithm multiple times, last time [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60556607/12671057). It does look intentional to me. You just need to realize that `i` keeps track of how many elements have been found (which is also the index for the next candidate).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `return list1[:i]` instead of returning the whole `list1`. Demo with that:

```
>>> odd_nr([1,2,3,4,5,6])
1
3
5
[1, 3, 5]
```

With your unusual but correct `for list1[i] in list1` and the according update of `i`, you're moving all the odd numbers to the front of the list and counting them with `i`. All that's left to do is to only return that front portion.

Alternatively, delete the unwanted back portion with `del list1[i:]` before you do `return list1`.